# SQL update in single query

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: `employee` and `employeedetails`.

`employee` looks like this:

```
id      name
----------------
1       Suresh
2       Ram
3       Ravi
```

`employeedetails` looks like this:

```
empid    salary
----------------
1        10000
2        5000
3        40000
```

I want to update `salary` field of a particular person. For this i know the employee name of the first table. Based on this, I need to write a single query that will update the `salary` field with single query. How can I do this?

For example, if I have to update Ravi's salary details, how can I do it in a single query?

Comment: i'm sure you've simplified the database structure considerably, but may i ask why the employee information is split like this? if i understand correctly it certainly is not for normalization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update employeedetails 
inner join employee on employeedetails.empid = employee.id
set salary = 1000
where employee.name = 'Ram'
```

Comment: I don't think Ram will be happy bunny ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
update employeedetails set salary=1000000 where empid in (select id from employee where name='suresh');
```

Comment: I doubt that salary is `text`.

Answer (score 1):

```
MERGE INTO employeedetails
   USING employee 
      ON employeedetails.empid = employee.id
         AND employee.name = 'Ravi'
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET salary = 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE employeedetails det 
SET salary=100 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
               FROM employee emp 
               WHERE name='Ravi'
                 AND det.empid = emp.id 
             )
;
```

Comment: A comment for the downvote would be appreciated. I proposed another way to do the update that was not proposed yet.

Comment: +1 The question only has the 'sql' tag, yours is standard SQL and widely implemented (as is mine :) The accepted answer is proprietary syntax (SQL Server?) I think your answer is superior to the accepted one for these reasons but SQL Server folk sure like their proprietary syntax ;)